# Spring Boot H2 console webServlet not registered by autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I have a very simple SpringBoot "app" demo with H2 in its dependencies. It's packed in `demo.jar`.

I can run it from the command line with `java -jar demo.jar` and it starts.

Then I can go to http://localhost:8080/h2 and H2 console is displayed.

This is on Windows.

Now - when I use exactly the same jar file and start it with exactly the same version of jre on macOS, the app starts, but the H2 console servlet is not registered and /h2 returns an error in the browser.

How is this possible?

I must have done something on my mac environment or sth, but what?

On Windows the H2 webServlet registers with:
   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/h2/*]

On macOS the second line is missing, so somehow the webServlet is not autoconfigured/recognized and mapped into /h2.

BTW. I tested the code with Spring Boot 2.0/1.5.10, tomcat/jetty, etc. It doesn't matter. There must be something wrong in the environment.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with illegal reflective access operations. I tried JDK 9.0.4 and it works, although there are some warnings listed.

Comment: is it actually throwing a some sort of exception in the logs related to illegal reflective access? If so you could try to make the IDE break on that specific exception that is being thrown then walk up the stacktrace and poke around to get an idea of what might be different between the two environments?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Brandon. To tell the truth, I'm not so sure about that. All I can tell is that by just setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 9.0.4 the app starts from the same jar file and the H2 console bean is discovered and registered properly. On 1.8 it acts like the H2 webServlet class wasn't even on the classpath - it returned JavaClassNotFound when I tried to instantiate it "manually". I don't have enough skills to diagnose it properly. Blaming the reflective "magic" behind Spring is actually the only logical reason I've got at the moment.